# Passing a javascript variable into a fusion chart constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fusioncharts

Everything works except getting the data to load in the chart.  When I view page source it shows ajaxData instead of the array of data that the variable contains.

I've tried JSON.Stringify, this., and a few other methods.  I can't find any examples on the fusion chart website of loading data with AJAX, all their examples involve putting the javascript in server side code such as PHP, which is something I'd rather avoid.  I'd simply like to load data with ajax and dump it in the chart.

```
$.ajax($assetsSearchUrl, {
        dataType: "text",
        accepts: {text: "application/json"},
        success: loadChart
    });

function loadChart(ajaxData)
{        

    var ageGroupChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'pie2d',
        renderAt: 'chartId',
        width: '400',
        height: '275',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        theme: 'ocean',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Assets",
                ....
                "showLegend": "0"
        },
        data : ajaxData
    }
}).render();
}
```

A working example without dynamic data.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
var ageGroupChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'pie2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '450',
    height: '300',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Split of Visitors by Age Group",
            ....
            "legendItemFontColor": '#666666'
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "label": "Teenage",
                "value": "1250400"
            }, 
            {
                "label": "Senior",
                "value": "491000"
            }
        ]
    }
}).render();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have what you were hoping for. I use `JSON.parse` to convert the json file string to an object, no `PHP` needed. Hope this helps!

```
var jsonUrl = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1jq6x";

FusionCharts.ready(function() {

  $.ajax(jsonUrl, {
    dataType: "text",
    accepts: {
      text: "application/json"
    },
    success: loadChart
  });

  function loadChart(jsonString) {
    var ageGroupChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: 'pie2d',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      width: '450',
      height: '300',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "Split of Visitors by Age Group",
          "legendItemFontColor": '#666666'
        },
        "data": JSON.parse(jsonString)
      }
    }).render();
  }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/zxvta33s/)

Comment: Thanks so much!  This is exactly what I needed.  I can now see what I was doing wrong.  At first I thought incorrectly that it had to do with the constructor, but this clearly illustrated to me that it was with the back end returning 'data' as part of the JSON.  Your example cleared up my mistake.  Thanks again!